# Case_when function in saving new variable in column to existing df

Tags: r, statistics, case

I am using case_when function to recategorize an existing variable that allowed for up to 6 race selections. Based on a determined logic I am reclassifying those races in a new variable (new_racecat) that only displays one race selection. I have pasted the first part of my code and the syntax works and the code completely runs. The problem I am having is that when I view my df (View(Racedata), this new variable is not appearing. How do I save this new variable into a new column in my existing data frame?

```
Racedata %>% 
  separate(col = "Race", into = c("race1", "race2", "race3", "race4", "race5", "race6"), sep = ";") %>% 
             mutate(new_racecat = case_when(race1 == "Native Hawaiian (Including Part-Hawaiian)" | 
                                           race2 == "Native Hawaiian (Including Part-Hawaiian)" | 
                                           race3 == "Native Hawaiian (Including Part-Hawaiian)" | 
                                           race4 == "Native Hawaiian (Including Part-Hawaiian)" |
                                           race5 == "Native Hawaiian (Including Part-Hawaiian)" | 
                                           race6 == "Native Hawaiian (Including Part-Hawaiian)" ~ "Native Hawaiian",
```

Comment: You need to assign the output back to the variable. `Racedata <- Racedata %>% separate(col = "Race", into = c("race1", "race2", "race3", ......rest of your code`

Answer (score 0):

Pipe operator (`%>%`) only inputted your `Racedata` to the operation. It does not save it. You can either do it like how @RonakShah commented but you can load `magrittr` and use `%<>%` instead of `%>%` whenever you pipe so it saves the output.